# How to change facebook app icon

Tags: facebook

I can't seem to find the right location of the settings since facebook redesigned admin panel ... screenshots appreciated , I can only change screenshots and banners but not the app icon itself
thanks

Comment: It's in the App Details section, or https://developers.facebook.com/x/apps/<put id here>/app-details. You have to submit app details for review for it to show up though.

Comment: Having this problem myself...I changed the "logo" in the lower section.  Does one need to Submit now before it will actually change?

Comment: Yeah I got confused because now it's 1000x1000px thanks Bill

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** Since "logo" is no longer listed as an option, I assume they have changed the setup form slightly...

New link: 
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app_id]/app-details/.

Under the section: "Icons"...
[Heres the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines#icons)

Scroll to the next section to see something which might be of interest too:
Promotional images (Cover image & Banners).

**NOTE:** You may have to do some image editing before uploading to meet the dimension restrictions they have in place (at the time of this post: 1024 x 1024 and size <= 5MB).

Answer (score 19):

[https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[your-app-id]/app-details/](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/%5Byour-app-id%5D/app-details/) -> "logo" is the way to go. If you uploaded a logo a while ago, it may look like the option to change it is not available, because your old logo isn't showing up (it's just a standard facebook image). That's because your old logo is probably too small. Upload a new logo, and your logo will change.

Info: It's **not** necessary to submit your app for approval first.

Comment: I found that changes to app details do require submission/review before they appear live.

Comment: Logo is no longer listed... which image is used now?

Comment: Hi Jimmy_m, which permissions i need to select for the approval of app thumbnail icon?